# Why I can't use the second vCPU for my pods on a e2-medium machine type?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

As Google refers [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture):

> For a 2vCPUs machine type , the allocatable CPU= Capacity- Reserved =
> 2000mCPU- 6% of the first CPU- 1% of the second CPU= 2000mCPU-60mCPU
> -10mCPU=1930 mCPU

I have already confirmed that for a `e2-standard` machine type with 2vCPU.

However, for a `e2-medium` machine with 2vCPU the allocatable CPU is 940mCPU.

Why I can't use the second vCPU for my pods on a `e2-medium` machine type?

Comment: May be related: note that while e2-standard does have 2 vCPU, e2-medium has 2x half vCPU. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types

Comment: Did you try the same with `small` and `micro` ? What are the results ?

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23289918

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting it as a **Community Wiki** as this answer is is largely based on the one, already posted by [Kostas Tsakos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9050798/kostas-tsakos) and is actually its expansion.

Let me add some more official source. This information can be also found in [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#June_02_2020) (June 02, 2020) thus it is available in the official GCP documentation:

> As part of ensuring better representation of available resources on
> the node for e2 burstable node types, GKE has decided to  **reduce the
> allocatable CPU resources available to schedule user workloads (known
> as the  [node allocatable
> resources](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu))
> on  `e2-micro`,  `e2-small`, and  `e2-medium`  machine types.**
>
> ##### What do I need to know?
>
> Today,  `e2-micro`,  `e2-small`, and  `e2-medium`  have 1930 mCPU of
> allocatable resources for Kubernetes to schedule Pods on per node, and
> following this change it will be 940m CPU. Kubernetes uses the node
> allocatable resources during scheduling to decide how many Pods it
> should place on the node.  **If your workloads are currently
> requesting more CPU resources than what will be available after
> upgrading, they may become unscheduled after upgrade.**
>
> We are making this change in order to more accurately represent the
> resources available in these machine types. These machine types can
> temporarily burst to 2 vCPUs, but this is not sustained.  **The
> underlying compute capabilities and resources are not changing**, the
> machines retain the ability to temporarily burst to 2 vCPU, this
> change only affects how many resources the Kubernetes scheduler
> considers when allocating Pods to nodes.
>
> When your cluster is  **upgraded to 1.14.10-gke.42, 1.15.11-gke.18,
> 1.16.8- gke.17, or 1.17.5-gke.5**  (whether you perform this  [manually](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster)
> or you are automatically upgraded), your workloads may become
> unscheduled if there are not enough allocatable resources in the
> cluster.

As already mentioned in comments by [SYN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5607207/syn), this is aplicable to [shared-core machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore) which leverage [CPU bursting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#cpu-bursting) capability, that allows them to use up to 2vCPUs for short periods of time. This means the actual computing power available for most of the time is far lower than 2vCPUs. As you can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#e2_shared-core_machine_types):

> When you use E2 shared-core machine types, your VM runs two vCPUs
> simultaneously, shared on one physical core, for a specific fraction
> of time, depending on the machine type.
>
> - `e2-micro`  sustains 2 vCPUs, each for 12.5% of  [CPU time](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time), totaling 25% vCPU time.
> - `e2-small`  sustains 2 vCPUs, each at 25% of  [CPU time](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time), totaling 50% of vCPU time.
> - `e2-medium`  sustains 2 vCPUs, each at 50% of  [CPU time](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time), totaling 100% vCPU time.
>
> Each vCPU can burst up to 100% of CPU time, for short periods, before
> returning to the time limitations above.

Please also note the reference in the table:

> 1Fractional vCPU of 0.25, 0.5, or 1.0 with 2 vCPUs exposed to the
> guest operating system.

which means that although the available CPU time on all the above mentioned machine types differs significantly, each of them exposes 2 vCPUs to the guest operating system (in this case **GKE node**).

So what was actually introduced is the adjustment of allocatable resources for Kubernetes to schedule Pods on node (decrease from 1930 mCPU to 940m CPU) so that it reflects more accurately the actual resources available on these machine types.

Answer (score 1):

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23289918

As google said on May 24th 2020:

Today, e2-micro, e2-small and e2-medium have 1930 mCPU of allocatable resources for Kubernetes to schedule Pods on per node, and following this change, it will be 940mCPU. Kubernetes uses the node allocatable resources during scheduling to decide how many Pods it should place on the node. If your workloads are currently requesting more CPU resources than what will be available after upgrading, they may become unscheduled after upgrade.